# How to stop Gstreamer from trying to initialize X11

Tags: python, x11, gstreamer, pygst

I've been trying to create a simple audio-player which i want to run from the commandline, for this I've used `Gstreamer` and the `pygst` python bindings and my code so far looks like this:

```
import pygst
pygst.require('0.10')
import gst
import os

class Player(object):
    mp3stream = "http://http-live.sr.se/p1-mp3-192"

    def __init__(self):
        self.pipeline = gst.Pipeline("RadioPipe")
        self.player = gst.element_factory_make("playbin", "player")
        self.pipeline.add(self.player)

        self.player.set_property('uri', self.mp3stream)
        self.pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)

player = Player()

while 1:
    if(1 == 2):
        break
```

Now for some reason, when I run this code I get the following warnings:

```
** (radio.py:7803): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=f12629ad79391c6f12cbbc1a50ccbcc8 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
```

I can play music without a problem, but I would very much get rid of these warnings, now I assume that the `Gstreamer` library for some reason tries to start something that requires `X11` but isn't necessary for the audioplaying part. Any comments on the validity of this assumption are most welcome.

Can I import something else or pass some sort of flag to stop Gstreamer from trying to initialize `X11`?

**EDIT 1**

I've tried adding this:

```
fakesink = gst.element_factory_make("fakesink", "fakesink")
self.player.set_property("video-sink", fakesink)
```

Which according to the [documentation](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/playbin.html) the above code will disable the automatic enabling of video-streaming. This does however not fix my problem with the warnings.

**EDIT 2**

Okay so the `element(?) playbin` is something like a ready-made piping of several audio and video related stuff, I'm sorry I can't explain it better for now. However it seems that playbin initializes some `elements(?)` that tries to access `X11`. I'm guessing that since I'm not playing anything videorelated it doesn't crash. I've managed to edit some of the `playbin elements(?)` but none of them fixes the `X11` warning.

The current code looks like this:

```
self.pipeline = gst.Pipeline("RadioPipe")

self.player = gst.element_factory_make("playbin", "player")
pulse = gst.element_factory_make("pulsesink", "pulse")
fakesink = gst.element_factory_make("fakesink", "fakesink")

self.player.set_property('uri', channel)
self.player.set_property("audio-sink", pulse)
self.player.set_property("video-sink", fakesink)

self.pipeline.add(self.player)
```

The questionmark after element has to do with me not being sure that is the correct wording.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to disable the `video` flag in playbin's `flag` properties. Alternately, if you do need video and know which video sink you need, set the `video-sink` property accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm completely new to gstreamer so I'm not sure if I followed you correctly. But if I understood things correctly that only disables the automatic enabling of video-streaming, which is a good thing disabling in my case since I don't need it.

Comment: Ok. I just realized that this is not an answer to your question. I initially assumed that a video sink was being tried and generated the warning, This does not appear to be the case. Could you run `gst-inspect` and grep for `hal`? It's the only gstreamer plugin I see that directly references DBUS.

Comment: I ran `gst-inspect-0.10 | grep hal` and that outputs nothing. From my understanding so far, shouldn't it exist something else that I can pass instead of `playbin` to the element factory that only enalbes audio streams?

Comment: `playbin` should do that. (as an aside, I suggest you use `playbin2` instead. but I doubt that will make the warning go away). I'll be deleting this answer shortly.

Comment: I still think that even though this isn't the correct answer it points out that you can disable the video-streaming. Our discussion might be useful for others. Oh and thanks a ton for your time! :)